# Using JSOUP to get the first valid image in a HTML String

Tags: java, android, string, image, jsoup

This is my code but sometimes it fails to get a valid image for some HTML String.

If I log every images variable in the loop I can see that a valid image exists but my code use another one sometimes not valid or the function return a null image.

what's wrong?
thanks

```
    private String getFirstImage(String htmlString){

    if(htmlString==null) return null;

    String img ="";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);
    Elements imgs = doc.getElementsByTag("img");



     for (Element imageElement : imgs) {
         if(imageElement!=null){
         //for each element get the srs url
         img = imageElement.absUrl("src");
            if( !img.contains("doubleclick.net") &&
                !img.contains("feedburner.com") &&
                !img.contains("feedsportal.com") &&
                !img.contains("ads"))

                    return img;
         }
     }

     return null;
}
```

/************* EDIT --> EXAMPLE

```
htmlString <p><a rel="attachment wp-att-182120" href="http://apple.hdblog.it/2013/09/08/arrivano-le-prime-immagini-rubate-della-scheda-logica-di-iphone-5c/logic5c/"><img height="390" alt="logic5c" width="520" src="http://apple.hdblog.it/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/logic5c-520x390.jpg"></a> <p>Nella rubrica “componenti leaked quotidiani” fa arrivo la scheda logica di iPhone 5C, grazie a diversi scatti fotografici diffusi tramite il social network cinese Weibo. Ormai sembra assodato che per Apple sia impossibile limitare le fughe di notizie quando sono previsti lanci di prodotti a breve distanza dalla loro presentazione. Le fabbriche cinesi alle quali Apple si affida sono armai un “colabrodo” di foto e notizie, che fanno perdere un po’ la <em>magia</em> dei keynote Apple. <p>Purtroppo o per fortuna le fotografie in questione non rivelano molto riguardo l’hardware interno dell’iPhone 5C e lasciano spazio alle speculazioni. La disposizione dei fori delle viti e dei connettori nella parte superiore è uguale a <a href="http://apple.hdblog.it/2013/06/21/nuove-foto-mostrano-il-prossimo-iphone-5s-rumor/">quella già vista sulla scheda madre di iPhone 5S.</a> <p>Ma questo non è abbastanza per far pensare ad un hardware uguale tra iPhone 5S e 5C. Mentre il primo nasconderà sotto la sua scocca le novità ingegneristiche di Apple -leggi chip A7- l’iPhone 5C dovrebbe essere <strong>niente di più che un iPhone 5 con scocca in plastica</strong>. Ma siamo pronti a sorprese <a title="Ufficiale | Evento Apple il 10 settembre!" href="http://apple.hdblog.it/2013/09/03/da-confermare-evento-apple-10-settembre-secondo-nuove-informazioni/">per il prossimo 10 settembre</a>! <div><div></div></div>  <img height="1" width="1" src="http://rss.feedsportal.com/c/33112/f/537497/s/30f29429/sc/28/mf.gif" border="0"><br clear="all"><div><table border="0"><tr><td valign="middle"><a target="_blank" href="http://share.feedsportal.com/share/twitter/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fapple.hdblog.it%2F2013%2F09%2F08%2Farrivano-le-prime-immagini-rubate-della-scheda-logica-di-iphone-5c%2F&t=Arrivano+le+prime+immagini+rubate+della+Scheda+Logica+di+iPhone+5C"><img src="http://res3.feedsportal.com/social/twitter.png" border="0"></a> <a target="_blank" href="http://share.feedsportal.com/share/facebook/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fapple.hdblog.it%2F2013%2F09%2F08%2Farrivano-le-prime-immagini-rubate-della-scheda-logica-di-iphone-5c%2F&t=Arrivano+le+prime+immagini+rubate+della+Scheda+Logica+di+iPhone+5C"><img src="http://res3.feedsportal.com/social/facebook.png" border="0"></a> <a target="_blank" href="http://share.feedsportal.com/share/linkedin/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fapple.hdblog.it%2F2013%2F09%2F08%2Farrivano-le-prime-immagini-rubate-della-scheda-logica-di-iphone-5c%2F&t=Arrivano+le+prime+immagini+rubate+della+Scheda+Logica+di+iPhone+5C"><img src="http://res3.feedsportal.com/social/linkedin.png" border="0"></a> <a target="_blank" href="http://share.feedsportal.com/share/gplus/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fapple.hdblog.it%2F2013%2F09%2F08%2Farrivano-le-prime-immagini-rubate-della-scheda-logica-di-iphone-5c%2F&t=Arrivano+le+prime+immagini+rubate+della+Scheda+Logica+di+iPhone+5C"><img src="http://res3.feedsportal.com/social/googleplus.png" border="0"></a> <a target="_blank" href="http://share.feedsportal.com/share/email/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fapple.hdblog.it%2F2013%2F09%2F08%2Farrivano-le-prime-immagini-rubate-della-scheda-logica-di-iphone-5c%2F&t=Arrivano+le+prime+immagini+rubate+della+Scheda+Logica+di+iPhone+5C"><img src="http://res3.feedsportal.com/social/email.png" border="0"></a></td><td valign="middle"></td></tr></table></div><br><br><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/174726694371/u/49/f/537497/c/33112/s/30f29429/sc/28/rc/1/rc.htm"><img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/174726694371/u/49/f/537497/c/33112/s/30f29429/sc/28/rc/1/rc.img" border="0"></a><br><a href="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/174726694371/u/49/f/537497/c/33112/s/30f29429/sc/28/rc/2/rc.htm"><img src="http://da.feedsportal.com/r/174726694371/u/49/f/537497/c/33112/s/30f29429/sc/28/rc/2/rc.img" border="0"></a><
09-08 12:04:08.736: D/GoogleReader(539): image http://apple.hdblog.it/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/logic5c-520x390.jpg
09-08 12:04:08.747: D/GoogleReader(539): image http://rss.feedsportal.com/c/33112/f/537497/s/30f29429/sc/28/mf.gif
09-08 12:04:08.775: D/GoogleReader(539): image http://res3.feedsportal.com/social/twitter.png
09-08 12:04:08.775: D/GoogleReader(539): image http://res3.feedsportal.com/social/facebook.png
09-08 12:04:08.775: D/GoogleReader(539): image http://res3.feedsportal.com/social/linkedin.png
09-08 12:04:08.785: D/GoogleReader(539): image http://res3.feedsportal.com/social/googleplus.png
09-08 12:04:08.785: D/GoogleReader(539): image http://res3.feedsportal.com/social/email.png
09-08 12:04:08.785: D/GoogleReader(539): image http://da.feedsportal.com/r/174726694371/u/49/f/537497/c/33112/s/30f29429/sc/28/rc/1/rc.img
09-08 12:04:08.866: D/GoogleReader(539): image http://da.feedsportal.com/r/174726694371/u/49/f/537497/c/33112/s/30f29429/sc/28/rc/2/rc.img
09-08 12:04:08.866: D/GoogleReader(539): image http://da.feedsportal.com/r/174726694371/u/49/f/537497/c/33112/s/30f29429/sc/28/rc/3/rc.img
09-08 12:04:08.866: D/GoogleReader(539): image http://da.feedsportal.com/r/174726694371/u/49/f/537497/c/33112/s/30f29429/a2.img
09-08 12:04:08.916: D/GoogleReader(539): image http://pi.feedsportal.com/r/174726694371/u/49/f/537497/c/33112/s/30f29429/a2t.img
09-08 12:04:08.916: D/GoogleReader(539): image http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/hd-blog/~4/4dvgXhJMTt8
```

In this example the "http://apple.hdblog.it/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/logic5c-520x390.jpg" is ok but my code does not use it :S... I don't know why

Comment: When you say 'valid' do you mean non-ad based image? Or does it have to meet other criteria?

Comment: the criteria is the if statement :)

Comment: Can you post specific html examples that you know don't work but should.

Comment: Your code seems ok. I aggree with @btse. If you want more help, please provide html examples.

Comment: I have updated my question with a sample code (log ;)) directly from the app

Comment: @UsiUsi did you try pasting below code into your ide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this example the
>   "http://apple.hdblog.it/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/logic5c-520x390.jpg"
>   is ok but my code does not use it :S... I don't know why

You need to change your filter since

```
            !img.contains("ads"))
```

...

```
http://apple.hdblog.it/wp-content/uplo**ads**/2013/09/logic5c-520x390.jpg
```

Seems that the links contains "ads" and gets filtered.

Maybe something like:

```
            !img.contains("/ads/"))
```

Why are you adding this filter? Maybe I can provide a better suggestion than this one.

Comment: Sure, I'm waiting for a better solution! Thanks :)

Comment: So, where you able to get the missing candidate? Did you find out how to filter out ads without using "ads" ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import java.io.IOException;

public class StackoverflowTest {

    //The url of the website. This is just an example
    private static final String webSiteURL = "http://apple.hdblog.it/2013/09/08/arrivano-le-prime-immagini-rubate-della-scheda-logica-di-iphone-5c/logic5c/";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackoverflowTest sot = new StackoverflowTest();
        sot.getFirstImage(webSiteURL);
    }

    private String getFirstImage(String htmlString){

        try {

            //Connect to the website and get the html
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(webSiteURL).get();

            //Get all elements with img tag ,
            Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("img");

            for (Element el : img) {

                //for each element get the srs url
                String src = el.absUrl("src");
                if(!src.contains("doubleclick.net") &&
                        !src.contains("feedburner.com") &&
                        !src.contains("feedsportal.com") &&
                        !src.contains("ads"))

                System.out.println("Image Found!");
                System.out.println("src attribute is : "+src);
                return src;
            }

            return null;

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("There was an error");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: hmmm. did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a space after your if statement, and an if statement without curly braces only reads the next line. Try adding brackets to your inner if statement.

Comment: mmm I can't understand your suggestion. If you refer at the return img; I've already tried without success to do {return img;}